# How do you convert Timestamp to normal time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am having this issue where when I post my timestamp shows excessive amount of information as shown in the image[image: Timestamp]

However I am wondering how do you convert this to just time and date without GMT or year for example Sat Apr 03 14:00:00.

My add.java

```
    private void uploadData(String imageURL) {


        CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                .document(user.getUid()).collection("Post Images");
        String id = reference.document().getId();
        String description = descET.getText().toString();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", id);
        map.put("description", description);
        map.put("imageUrl", imageURL);
        map.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());


        map.put("name", user.getDisplayName());
        map.put("profileImage",String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl()));
        map.put("likeCount", 0);
        map.put("Comments", "");
        map.put("uid", user.getUid());

        reference.document(id).set(map)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            System.out.println();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: "+task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


    }
```

my profile.java

```
    private void uploadImage(Uri uri) {
        StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

        reference.putFile(uri)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            String imageURL = uri.toString();
                                            UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder();
                                            request.setPhotoUri(uri);

                                            user.updateProfile(request.build());
                                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                            map.put("profileImage", imageURL);
                                            map.put("date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                                                    .document(user.getUid())
                                                    .update(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    else
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Any help here would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: I have downvoted [because you have shown no search effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [because you have posted too much irrelevant code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Like this:

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          String normalTime = convertTimestampToNormalTime("Sat Apr 03 14:19:53 
          GMT+01:00 2021");
          System.out.println(normalTime);
     }

     public static String convertTimestampToNormalTime(String timestamp) {
          String[] arrOfTime = timestamp.split("GMT");
          return arrOfTime[0];
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

### java.time

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. For a conversion from one string format to another, use two formatters:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter inputParser
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
private static final DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

With them do:

```
String givenStringDate = "Sat Apr 03 14:19:53 GMT+01:00 2021";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(givenStringDate, inputParser);
String outputString = zdt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).format(outputFormatter);
System.out.println(outputString);
```

Output is:

> Sat Apr 03 14:00

Now we’re at it, consider using Java’s built-in localized format for the audience in question, for example:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                .withLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
```

> 03/04/21 14:00

You can make the format longer by specifying `MEDIUM`, `LONG` or `FULL`.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.